# ASP.Net Web Api Controller Design Guidelines

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have multiple resources which I want to expose through following URIs

1. http:///countries               GET
2. http:///states?countryCode=**   GET
3. http:///persons                 GET, POST, PUT, DELETE

I am using Asp.Net Web API to build RESTful service to access these resource.

What would be the best practice while creating controllers for these? Should I create separate controller for each resource? Or there is some way to map these urls to actions of a single controller?

Single controller class will help If I use DependencyResolver as I saw DependencyResolver can return instance of a single Controller. (I may be wrong here)

I need dependency resolver as my controller classes will have some repository object through constructor injection.

I won't use any IoC, only poor man's DI.

**One Addition**

I have successfully designed this problem in WCF Web Api used for REST, but not in Asp.Net Web API. I am new in this.

Answer (score 3):

Create a separate controller for each resource.

It's a bad idea to ruin your API because you are having DI issues.

The free [Apigee Web API Design ebook](http://apigee.com/about/content/web-api-design) is very short, extremely good and certainly worth reading.

Comment: Thanks Neil...but didn't get your comment "It's a bad idea to ruin your API because you are having DI issues." If I used separate controller then how to resolve constructor dependency using dependency resolver??

Comment: Hi Bijit. Maybe I misunderstood you, but it sounded like the main reason you were considering a single controller for Countries, States and Persons was that you had some complication with automatically injecting dependencies into multiple controllers. If this is the case you might want to post a separate question; If not, my bad.

Comment: You got right Neil. Any way i solved the issue using IHttpControllerActivator instead of IDependencyResolver for composing Controllers.

Comment: Based on SOLID principles you should put them into different controllers. And it's extremely easy to set up DI by using framework such as autofac.

Answer (score 0):

As Neil mentioned above, the best practice would be to create 3 different controllers:

- CountriesController
- StatesController
- PersonsController

If you derive them from ApiController, they will be automatically available under the following urls:

- /api/countries
- /api/states
- /api/persons

If you derive from Controller, they will be available under the following urls:

- /countries
- /states
- /persons

As for the dependency injection, you could derive from your own BaseController and inject all the dependencies there if that's what you absolutely need. Or each class could require a different interface and have your DI resolve that.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple different urls can be mapped to the actions of a single controller, in Web API. Here's how it can be done:

In WebApiConfig.cs under the App_Start folder, the default mapping gets automatically created as:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

To map action methods as well, add an `{action}` parameter in the `routeTemplate` in the above route, as follows:

```
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```

Now you can create a single Controller, with different Action Methods, to match your requests. The Controller actions would look like this:

```
    // Reached by /api/controllername/getcountries
    public IEnumerable<string> GetCountries()
    {
        // Custom code
    }


    // Reached by /api/controllername/getstates/countrycode
    public IEnumerable<string> GetStates(string id)
    {
        // id contains the countrycode string
    }
```

Make sure that the action methods names still begin with the HTTP verbs: `Get | Put | Post | Delete`, though!